# Field deletion problem

Tags: entities

Whenever I try to delete a field associated to a content type, I get the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Attempt to create a field
>   field_cert_fields that does not exist on entity type node. in
>   Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig->getFieldStorageDefinition() (line 286
>   of core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php).

the field field_cert_field is not actually there in any of the content types.

How can i resolve this problem? Even if am getting this error, the field I wanted to delete is deleted.

**UPDATE**

---

I have a custom module that defines a custom field in 
**`/modules/certfield/src/Plugin/Field`** folder .I cant uninstall the module and it says :

> The following reason prevents SSl Cert Field from being uninstalled:
>   Fields pending deletion

once i removed the module manually when it cant uninstall via **`drush`** .  I guess that makes the issue . Anyway to get rid of this ?

Comment: Are you defining fields in code somewhere?

Comment: Is it because of code ? Or not because of any other field on content types ?

Comment: Why its minus voted ;(  ?? . I am not defining that field (**field_cert_fields**) anywhere